# MongoDB query if dictionary field has particular value

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a field called `options` which has structure `{"options": { "a": "Opt A", "b": "Opt B", "c": "Opt C", "d": "Opt D"}}` (dictionary is stored). I want to check if any one of them is empty `''` along with **other fields** and I am getting the following error.

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationFailure                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [111], line 8
      1 optlist = [
      2     {"$eq" : {"a": ""}}, 
      3     {"$eq" : {"b": ""}}, 
      4     {"$eq" : {"c": ""}}, 
      5     {"$eq" : {"d": ""}}
      6 ]
      7 query = { 'options': {"$or" : optlist}}
----> 8 pd.DataFrame(db.find(query))
```

with the following code

```
optlist = [
    {"$eq" : {"a": ""}}, 
    {"$eq" : {"b": ""}}, 
    {"$eq" : {"c": ""}}, 
    {"$eq" : {"d": ""}}
]
query = { 'options': {"$or" : optlist}}
pd.DataFrame(db.find(query))
```

I fixed it with the code

```
        query = {"$and" : [{
            "$or":
            [
                {"options.a" : ""}, 
                {"options.b" : ""}, 
                {"options.c" : ""}, 
                {"options.d" : ""}
            ]}, query]
        }
```

Comment: How large is the collection? Is the error because your query is returning lot of documents? Can you run the query with a limit and see if you are getting the error - `db.find(query).limit(10)`?

Comment: @user11666461 I fixed it with the code with the above code.

Comment: Can you explain what resulted in the error? And how the fix worked? - why `$and` is done on the `query` again?

Comment: @user11666461 when I tried `{'$or': [{'options.a': '', ... }]}` it had worked but I had to check other fields too. I thought that I could check structure of option by `{"option" : {'or' : ...}}` which didn't work. But adding `{'$and' : [query, {$or, ... }]` worked.